# Gmail and free third party GPG/PGP services

Tags: gmail, encryption

I signed up for a free PGP key provider that worked with my Gmail account. I set it up to work with Apple Mail in Mac OS X Lion. Now, I realize I never use this encryption key, and I want to remove the service from my Gmail account setup. How can I find out what it is the service that I signed up for called, and how to remove it from my account?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to guess what you might be using, and until that is known removing it is tricky. Two possibilities to try work out what it is:

1. Check your Google authorisations - Have a look at the application listed [here](https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens), particularly anything listed as having access to Gmail.
2. Check your browser plugins - a number of services work via a plugin in your browser, so have a look at what is listed there. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in Firefox, or via `Wrench` → `Tools` → `Extensions` in Chrome.